# Sending Mail without User intervention in Android Application

Tags: android-emulator

I'm using the steps and code in the below link

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a)

It works for me in Emulator but it is not working in Real Phone devices.

Also there are no errors and no warnings.

Can anyone please help me in rectifying this.

Thanks in Advance.